# Error handling in Angularjs for deferred promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I built a factory to return data that uses an HTTP Get through a deferred promise.  It work great when it is the happy path and the url is correct.  But when there is an error I would like to catch it.  It seems that I am but a 500 error still shows in the console.  Is there a way to catch this also? Also, I want to do processing on the reject I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.  TIA

```
angular.module("accQueries")
    .factory('leaseFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

            return {
                leases: '',
                makeRequest: function (url) {
                    // Create the deferred object
                    var deferred = $q.defer();

                    $http.get(url).then(function (resp) {
                        deferred.resolve(resp.data);
                    })
                    // potentially catch http error here??
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        deferred.reject(err);
                        console.log('rejected  : ' + err );
                        console.dir(err);
                        this.leases = '';
                    });

                    return deferred.promise;
                },
                // Return a single lease based on lease number
                getLease: function (pLeaseNum) {
                    this.leases = this.makeRequest("http://someserver/AccruentQA_DB/webresources/restfulservices.latbllease/leaseNumber/" + pLeaseNum);
                    // Return the lease object stored on the service
                    return this.leases;
                },
                // Return all leases based on lease name
                getLeases: function () {
                    this.leases = this.makeRequest("http://someserver/AccruentQA_DB/webresources/restfulservices.latbllease/name/");

                    // Return the lease object stored on the service
                    return this.leases;
                }
            };

        }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not needed to wrap a $http call in $q, because $http returns a promise itself. So just returning $http like this is sufficient:

```
makeRequest: function (url) {
   return $http.get(url);
}
```

If you would want to chain do something in the makeRequest function with the answers be4 passing it on, you can chain promises like so:

```
makeRequest: function (url) {
   return $http.get(url).then(function(response){
      //do something
      return response; 
   }, function(error){
      //do something
      return error;
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you that answered.  Definitely set me on the right path.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to prevent the HTTP error from appearing in the console.  The browser does that before it passes the results back to angular.   However, an error causes the `$http` promise to be rejected, which means you can handle it using the optional second argument to `then()`

```
return $http.get('url').then(
    function(response) { 
        this.leases = response.data;
    },
    function(response) {
        var statusCode = response.status;
        var response = response.data;
        // other error processing
        this.leases = '';
    }
}).then(function() { return this.leases; }
```

You can do various things depending on the status code and response data.  If your server emits an error 500, that's what `response.status` will be.  Timeouts have a status of 0.

You should also be aware that `getLease()` will return before the ajax request is complete.  You should return the promise, and then in the calling code, chain another `then()` to do something once the promise is resolved.